# Make Screen Time stop counting the time an app is in the background

Tags: macos, defaults, screen-time

On my Mac, Screen Time counts the time an app is in the background as part of the time I spent using it. For example, if I open Discord, use it for 1 minute, then keep the Discord window in the background while I use other apps for 59 minutes, Screen Time thinks I used Discord for 1 hour. Is there any way to make Screen Time stop counting time the app spends in the background? I'm on Catalina.

Comment: In the background as in *minimized* or behind another window?

Comment: Behind another window, but I'm willing to minimize things if that solves the problem.

Comment: In a broad sense screen time measures app usage by the criteria “running and doing something”. Discord is always updating so, it’s highly unlikely you’ll bypass this with a simple minimize action.  It’s important to note that simply moving a window to the “background” doesn’t suspend the running process

Comment: So I assume hiding doesn't work either?

Comment: Discord is constantly receiving messages so it’s “doing something.”  Hiding the user interface doesn’t suspend the process.